# Installing a package from another repo owned by my org results in a 401 in my github workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub workflow for running unit tests. My `package.json` references a private package from one of my organisations other repos. In my workflow, I have pulled in my secret, and also have  a `.npmrc` file but I'm getting a 401 when running `npm ci`, even though I've created a PAC and set that in my Repo Action Secrets. I've searched and tried multiple StackOverflow questions and none of the solutions have worked.

The install works locally, as I've added my PAC into my `.zshrc` file, and the `.npmrc` file picks it up and everything installs fine.

I have added the repo's that are allowed to use the package into the package settings under Manage Actions Access.

I have also created a PAC code, saved that as an Action Repo Secret:
[Action Repo Secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Uo5.png)

I then use my secret in my workflow:

```
name: Run Tests
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

env:
  NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NODE_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  Test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        node-version: [18.x]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: NPM install
        run: npm ci
      - name: NPM Test
        run: npm run test
```

And finally I have my .npmrc file

```
shamefully-hoist=true
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@OrgName:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN}
always-auth=true
strict-peer-dependencies=false
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

And when my workflow runs, I get the following:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-11-08T13_33_46_285Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

This is very similar to other questions but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work.
If there is a definitive answer, please link it.

Answer (score 0):

So to update, I've figured out what the issue was here.

The dependancy that I was trying to install, and the PAC I created for that package was working fine.

It was actually an issue with a dependancy of my package, which also required an API key, which I needed to add into my environment variables.

I didn't realise that installing my package also required me to pass in the API key for one of the dependancies.

So this is now working.